# Does breaking an outer loop allow the inner loop finish all it's execution?

Tags: java, nested-loops

Might be a simple question but, having two nested loops, if I execute a `break` over the outer one, will the inner one break immediately too; Or will it let it finish its execution, then break the outer one right after?

For example:

```
outer: for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        if (j == 5) break outer;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

Would this piece of code print numbers from `0` to `5` before it breaks the outer loop or would it print numbers from `0` to `10` instead?

Will the `System.out.println("test");` execute too?

Comment: You're asking what a piece of code will do? Run it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will print numbers from `0` to `4`.

5 not included, as the print is not executed when the condition is met `(j==5)`. If you wish to include it, change the condition to `(j>5)`.

Regarding your second question, no, `"test"` would never be printed. The labeled break finishes the outer loop (*with every statement inside, including the inner loop*) and ends your program's execution, by just printing:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

*Edit: tested and confirmed, above's the resultant output.*

Comment: This is the case because when the first for loop iterates once, the second one goes through ALL iterations before the first for loop even sees its second iteration. So when that break is initiated it stops everything inside, and it never even sees the 5th `System.out.println(j);`; Let alone the `System.out.println("test");`